# How to run a docker container declaratively on nixos server?

Tags: linux, docker, server, nix, nixos

How do I run a docker container declaratively on nixos server ? I am trying to run whoogle on a nix server and I don't wish to manually restart the whoogle container everytime I restart the server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After bit of guidance from the [r/nixos](https://reddit.com/r/nixos) community settled with this.

```
{ config, pkgs, ... }:

let
  host = "mydomain";
in
{
  virtualisation = {
    podman = {
      enable = true;
      dockerCompat = true;
    };
    oci-containers = {
      backend = "podman";
      containers.whoogle-search = {
        image = "benbusby/whoogle-search";
        autoStart = true;
        ports = [ "8080:5000" ]; #server locahost : docker localhost
      };
    };
  };
  services.nginx.virtualHosts = {
    "search.${host}" = {
      enableACME = true;
      forceSSL = true;
      locations."/".proxyPass = "http://localhost:8080";
    };
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Use `--restart always` with docker command at initial start
2. enable docker service to start at boot

And your container will start at boot

Comment: thanks, I just needed a declarative way in nix, so I wouldn't have to set this again.